# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

Sorry, for same type of question. I saw so many post in SO for stage failure. But none of those were able to resolve my issue. .While I'm running the commandDriver: Standard_D12_v2, Workers: Standard_D12_v2, 2-8 workers, 10.4 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.2.1, Scala 2.12)but it is throwing error.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.

Comment: can you share full error stack.

Answer (score 0):

one can solve this job aborted error, either changing the "spark configuration" in the cluster or either use "try_cast" function when you are getting this error while inserting data from one table to another table in databricks.

use dbr version : 10.4 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.2.1, Scala 2.12)

for spark configuartion edit the spark tab by editing the cluster and use below code  there.

"spark.sql.ansi.enabled false"

or use try_cast function.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/try-cast-azure-stream-analytics.
I've solved it.